# How can I get rid of the "Failed to get credentials for <AWSacc> operation error STS: GetSessionToken" when setting up aws-vault

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-vault

I am trying to set up aws-vault to access one specific AWS account.
I've set up my profile on config (region and role_arn) and run:

```
aws-vault add <profile>
```

with Access Key ID and Secret Access Key.
However when I run the following command I get this error:

```
aws-vault exec <profile>
```

> "error: exec: Failed to get credentials for  operation error STS: GetSessionToken, failed to resolve service endpoint, an AWS region is required, but was not found"

What am I doing wrong in here?

I've tried to setup the profiles for accessing aws-vault